# Shell script: Insert multiple lines into a file ONLY after a specified pattern appears for the FIRST time. (The pattern appears multiple times)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ed

I want to insert multiple lines into a file using shell script. Let us consider my original file: original.txt:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
bbb
ccc
.
.
.
```

and my insert file: toinsert.txt

```
111
222
333
```

Now I have to insert the three lines from the 'toinsert.txt' file ONLY after the line 'ccc' appears for the FIRST time in the 'original.txt' file. Note: the 'ccc' pattern appears more than one time in my 'original.txt' file. After inserting ONLY after the pattern appears for the FIRST time, my file should change like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
111
222
333
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
bbb
ccc
.
.
.
```

I should do the above insertion using a shell script. Can someone help me?

Note2: I found a similar case, with a partial solution:

`sed -i -e '/ccc/r toinsert.txt'  original.txt`

which actually does the insertion multiple times (for every time the ccc pattern shows up).

Comment: Would you please remove the PowerShell tags when you question is not about PowerShell? If it is you should elaborate a little more detailed. Thanks in advance. ;-)

Comment: As Olaf mentioned are you looking for a Powershell or shell solution?

Comment: Done. PowerShell tags removed. I am looking for a Shell script solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ed`, not `sed`, to edit files:

```sh
printf "%s\n" "/ccc/r toinsert.txt" w | ed -s original.txt
```

It inserts the contents of the other file after the first line containing `ccc`, but unlike your `sed` version, only after the first.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/ccc/!b;/ccc/r insertFile' file
```

Use a range:

If the current line is in the range following the first occurrence of `ccc`, break from further processing and implicitly print as usual.

Otherwise if the current line does contain `ccc`,insert lines from `insertFile`.

N.B. This uses the address `0` which allows the regexp to occur on line 1 and is specific to GNU sed.

or:

```
sed -e '/ccc/!b;r insertFile' -e ':a;n;ba' file
```

Use a loop:

If a line does not contain `ccc`, no further processing and print as usual.

Otherwise, insert lines from `insertFile` and then using a loop, fetch/print the remaining lines until the end of the file.

N.B. The `r` command insists on being delimited from other sed commands by a newline. The `-e` option simulates this effect and thus the sed commands are split across two `-e` options.

or:

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/ccc/!b;h;r insertFile' file
```

Use a flag:

If the hold space is not empty (the flag has already been set), no further processing and print as usual.

Otherwise, if the line does not contain `ccc`, no further processing and print as usual.

Otherwise, copy the current line to the hold space (set the flag) and insert lines from `insertFile`.

N.B. In all cases the `r` command inserts lines from `insertFile` after the  current line is printed.